# UIImageViewの画像をアスペクトを保ちながら最大にして上から表示させるには

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Xcode 9.4.1(Swift 4.1)を使っています。
UIImageViewで画像を表示させていますが、storyboard上よりcontent ModeをAspect Fillにして、まずUIImageViewいっぱいに最大化させます。そして、上下のはみ出た部分は表示させたくはないので、Clip to Boundsにチェックします。

しかし、画像が上下中央になっています。下の画像は見切れて表示されなくてもいいので、上揃い（画像上部が見えるように）配置したいと思っています。

どのように指定すればいいのでしょうか。
ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Comment: ストーリーボード上の設定のみで指定したいのであれば、難しいのではないでしょうか。コードがある程度介在してよいのであれば十分可能です。

Comment: こちろんコード介在OKです。どのようなコードで実現可能かご教示いただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 0):

ユーティリティメソッド的で申し訳ないですが、以下のようにUIImageViewにセットする画像をあらかじめ切り抜くコードを挟めばできます。

```
/// imageに指定された画像をtoSetImgViewに収まるようにクリップしてからセットする
/// - parameter image: UIImageViewにセットしたい画像
/// - parameter toSetImgView: 画像をセットしたいUIImageViewのインスタンス
func setResizedImageToUIImageView(image:UIImage, toSetImgView:UIImageView)
{
    let cImg:CGImage? = image.cgImage;
    if(cImg == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    //画像がうまく表示できるように画像を切り抜き
    let imgRef:CGImage? = cImg?.cropping(to: CGRect(x:0, y:0,width:image.size.width, height:toSetImgView.frame.size.height * image.size.width / toSetImgView.frame.size.width))
    if(imgRef == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let newImg = UIImage(cgImage: imgRef!, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)

    toSetImgView.image = newImg
}
```

本当はUIImageViewを継承してKVOでやりたかったのですがSwiftは不慣れなものでうまくいきませんでした。(たぶんSwift的には拙いコードになっていると思います。)
KVOでimageプロパティが変更されたことの通知を受け取れれば、上記処理をそこで呼び出すことでもっとスマートにできると思います。